# Need help understanding => symbol in Dart

Tags: dart, syntax

I came across the following Dart code while reading about first where. I wanted to understand what exactly is happening in this code as this is some syntax I am not familiar with, particularly the "=>" symbols.

```
void main() {
  final list = List<Book>.generate(10, (id) => Book(id));
  Book findBook(int id) => list.firstWhere((book) => book.id == id);

  print(findBook(2).name);
  print(findBook(4).name);
  print(findBook(6).name);
}

class Book {
  final int id;

  String get name => "Book$id";

  Book(this.id);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what is called `Syntaxic sugar`. It does not provide a special functionality but makes it easier for developer to write and read code.

In the cas of the `=>` symbol, it [is a shortcut for a function containing only a return statement](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions). So those two definitions are exactly the same:

```
String main() {
    return "Hello World"
}
```

```
String main() => "Hello World";
```

Note however, how the second one is way more readable.

So in your case if we unwrap everything your code would become:

```
void main() {
  final list = List<Book>.generate(10, (id) {
    return Book(id);
  });
  Book findBook(int id) {
    return list.firstWhere((book) {
      return book.id == id;
    });
  }

  print(findBook(2).name);
  print(findBook(4).name);
  print(findBook(6).name);
}

class Book {
  final int id;

  String get name {
    return "Book$id";
  }

  Book(this.id);
}
```